# Can a small perturbation of a diagonal matrix increase its smallest eigenvalue to any arbitrarily large value?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Let $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a diagonal positive semidefinite matrix with exactly $k$ positive entries in its diagonal, where $k<n$. Let $\epsilon$ be any arbitrarily small positive real number. Can we find a symmetric matrix $A=A(\epsilon)\neq 0$ such that $\|A\|_{\mathrm{op}} \leq \epsilon\; \lambda_{\textrm{min}}(S+A)$ ?

Here, $\|\cdot\|_{\mathrm{op}}$ denotes the operator norm, and $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}$ is the smallest eigenvalue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So, $S$ is given and you want to find $A$, such that the inequality holds for any arbitrarily small and $\epsilon$ right?

Comment: Yes, S is given, and we want to find such A.

Comment: In those scenarios, the best approach is to try to find a counterexample or a contradiction.

Comment: I have played with a toy example for n=2 and A is a rank-one perturbation. This leads to some condition on the unique positive diagonal entry of S. However, I'm not sure this would lead to any conclusion as this is just a rank-one perturbation while here one can use any symmetric perturbation.

Comment: Is $S$ a nonnegative matrix i.e. other diagonal entries are $0$ ?

Comment: @M-Brust The issue here is that if $\epsilon$ can be chosen to be any arbitrarily small positive number, that would mean that the operator norm of $A$ should be zero.

Comment: A special case is when S is the identity matrix. Then, the matrix $A=\lambda \mathbb{I}$ for $\lambda\leq \epsilon/(1-\epsilon)$, would do the job! I feel that the general case would work too, but don't know how to start.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes, S has nonnegative entries in the diagonal. The more interesting case is when S contains some zero(s) in its diagonal.

Comment: @KBS I should remark that A can be chosen to depend on the given $\epsilon$.

Comment: You should also remark (in the original question), that $S $ is non-negative. From the question as it is formualated right now, $S$ could have a negative diagonal entry. From the comments it seems that you are making such an assumption.

Comment: @Thomas I just made an edit according to your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @M-Brust I guess you also mean $\|A\|< \varepsilon \lambda_{min}(S+A)$ right? Otherwise you can just take $A=0$ since all non-zero entries on the diagonal of $S$ are positive.

Comment: @AnCar oh you're right, the matrix A should be non-trivial as well. I added this remark. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have come to the conclusion that $A$ cannot be block diagonal. I get contradictions in that case. Need to double check though.

Answer (score 1):

As both $A,S$ are symmetric, we get
$$\lambda_\text{min}(S+A) = \min_{v\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \Vert v \Vert=1} \langle v, (S+A) v \rangle.$$
As $S$ has nontrivial kernel, we can pick $w\in Ker(S)$ with $\Vert w \Vert=1$ and get
$$ \lambda_\text{min}(S+A) \leq \langle w, (S+A) w\rangle = \langle w,Aw\rangle \leq \Vert A \Vert_\text{op} \Vert w \Vert^2 = \Vert A \Vert_\text{op}. $$
Then your desired inequality would imply that
$$ \Vert A \Vert_\text{op} \leq \varepsilon \Vert A \Vert_\text{op}, $$
which does not work for $A\neq 0$ and $0\leq \varepsilon<1 $.

Note that the same proof works for any symmetric $S$ with nontrivial kernel. If $S$ admits a negative eigenvalue, we test on the corresponding eigenvector and reach the same contradiction. For your conclusion to hold, we need that the lowest eigenvalue of $S$ is strictly positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the case when $n=2$ and $S=\begin{pmatrix}s & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ for some fixed $s>0$.

We are looking for a symmetric $A$, therefore we can write $A=U^T\begin{pmatrix}sx & 0 \\ 0 & sy \end{pmatrix}U$ for some real numbers $x,y$ and some orthogonal matrix $U$. Since conjugating a matrix doesn't change its eigenvalues, we need to find $x,y$ such that $s\max(|x|,|y|)\leq \varepsilon \lambda_{min}(B)$, where $B:=USU^T+\begin{pmatrix}sx & 0 \\ 0 & sy \end{pmatrix}$, with $x,y$ depending on $\varepsilon$.

Now orthogonal matrices in dimension two are either rotations of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$ or reflections of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$.

In both cases ($U$ being either a reflection or a rotation), we get
\begin{equation*}
P_B(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix} s\cos^2\theta+sx-\lambda & s\sin\theta\cos\theta\\ s\sin\theta\cos\theta & s\sin^2\theta +sy -\lambda\end{vmatrix} = \lambda^2 -s(1+x+y)\lambda+s^2(xy+x\sin^2\theta+y\cos^2\theta),
\end{equation*}

so $\lambda_{min}=s\frac{1+x+y-\sqrt{(1+x+y)^2-4(x\sin^2\theta+y\cos^2\theta+xy)}}{2}$.

Therefore the inequality we want to satisfy reduces to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\max(|x|,|y|)\leq 1+x+y-\sqrt{(1+x+y)^2-4(x\sin^2\theta+y\cos^2\theta+xy)}. 
\end{equation*}

By assuming without loss of generality that $|x|\geq |y|$ and dividing both sides by $|x|$, we see that $\frac{RHS}{|x|}$ should be unbounded (as a function of $x,y$) for the inequality to be satisfied (for small enough $\varepsilon$). But note that $\frac{RHS}{|x|}\leq 2+\frac{1}{|x|}$, so we can restrict our search to the case $|y|\leq|x|<1$. In fact, setting
\begin{equation*}
 f(x,y)=1+x+y-\sqrt{(1+x+y)^2-4(x\sin^2\theta+y\cos^2\theta+xy)},
\end{equation*}
the only hope for the inequality to be satisfied for an appropriate choice of $x,y$ with $|y|\leq |x|$ is that $\limsup_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,y)}{|x|}=\infty$. Clearly, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y)=0$, so using L'Hopital's rule, we need that $\lim_{x\to 0}|\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,y)|=\infty$.

However, $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,y)=1-\frac{1+x-y-2\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{(1+x+y)^2-4(x\sin^2\theta+y\cos^2\theta+xy)}}$ (assuming my computations are correct :D), and this clearly tends to $2\sin^2\theta\leq 2$ as $x\to 0$ (recall that $|y|\leq |x|$).

Therefore, for $n=2$ and for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small, no $A$ can be found to satisfy the required inequality.